# jquery: animation the .hide instead of just hiding the element

Tags: jquery, css

I am currently hiding and showing elements on my dom with a little button that rotates upon click back and forth:

```
$(".buttonLayout").on("click", function () {
    var classTohide = ".classToHide" + this.id

    if (!isRotated) {
        $(classTohide).hide()
        isRotated = true
        $(this).addClass("rotate-180back");
        $(this).removeClass("rotate-180");
    }
    else {
        $(classTohide).show()
        isRotated = false
        $(this).addClass("rotate-180");
        $(this).removeClass("rotate-180back");
    }
});
```

It really works beautifully, but the issue is, that the elements simply disappear in within one frame and it looks a bit confusing.

How can I make this behavior better? So that instead of just hiding, it kinda "moves up" and then hides?

Any tips? :)

**EDIT**: this is my css:

```
.buttonLayout {
    width: 15px;
}

.rotate-180 {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: transform 100ms;
}

.rotate-180back {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 100ms;
}
```

And this is my div (long):

```
    <div class="MainDiv">
        <table class="mainTable">
            @{ 
                var position = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < Model.MainNodes.Count(); i++)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mainCat">
                            @Model.MainNodes[i].name
                        </div>
                        <!--subcategory-->
                        <table class="subTable">
                                @for (int y = 0; y < Model.MainNodes[i].children.Count(); y++)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="subCat">
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Model.MainNodes[i].children[y].name

                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="containerLayout">
                                                                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/icons/icon-open.png")" id="@position" class="buttonLayout" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--subsubcategory-->
                                            <table class="subsubTable">
                                                @{
                                                    string classToHide = "classToHide" + position;

                                                    for (int x = 0; x < Model.MainNodes[i].children[y].children.Count(); x++)
                                                    {
                                                        <tr class="subsubCat @classToHide">
                                                            <td>
                                                                @Model.MainNodes[i].children[y].children[x].name
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <button class="button CustomButton Save" onClick="AddSubSub(@y);">SubSub löschen</button>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    }
                                                    <tr class="@classToHide">
                                                        <td >
                                                            <button class="button CustomButton Save" onClick="AddSubSub(@y);">Neue SubSub hinzufügen</button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }

                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    position++;
                            }
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: As it seems you're using `jQuery`, you can simply use `slideUp` and `slideDown` (or `slideToggle`) methods that it provides. Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: i tried slideUp but it just does nothing and then the div is gone after a few millisecs. Its hard to provide an example but Ill edit the question a little

Comment: Note that can't use `.slideUp()` on a `td` or `tr` - which would do what you describe.  It looks like you *are* trying to do this on a tr `<tr class='@classToHide'>`.   You'll need to add a div in each td then animate those - then use the slideUp callback to .hide() the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried `slideUp` but it just does nothing and then the div is gone after a few millisecs

You cannot use `.slideUp` / `.slideDown` on a `tr` or `td`.

One work-around, though there are probably better solutions, is to wrap the content of each `td` in a `div` or `span` and then animate those, example:

```js
$("#close1").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").slideUp()
})
$("#close2").click(function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  tr.find("td>div,td>span,td>img").slideUp(() => tr.hide());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td><button id='close1'>close immediately</button></td></tr>
<tr><td><span>Content 3</span></td><td><div>Content 4</div></td><td><button id='close2'>close with slide</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you. your comment explaind it and I got it to work right away :)